# PHP Session Name not working

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am using same code in 2 different server. Actually tring to access cakephp session out of cakephp.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(!session_id()){
    session_name('CAKEPHP');
    session_start();
}
print_r($_SESSION);
```

At one server I am getting the session values.

Where as another is not showing anything.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Perhaps the other server has a different session name?

Comment: don't you think `session_start();` should be outside `if`? don't know your scenario. also check `session.auto_start` if it is enabled you are never going to get inside the `if` condition.

Comment: `session_id` returns an empty string if session not started

Answer (score -2):

I found the issue.

In cakephp core.php it was

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake'
));
```

I changed it to php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'
));
```

And it worked.

Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: You are NOT encouraged to use coer PHP functions over cakePHP